# Join two strings into an array or object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two strings that I want to join together into one array (or maybe an object).

```
1:  [atty_hourly_rate],[paralegal_hourly_rate],[advanced_deposit]
2:  250,150,500
```

I'd like to access the 500 value, which I know is the advanced_deposit. I'm not sure that the string will always come in this order, so I'd like to set up an array to something like this:

```
values[atty_hourly_rate] = 250
values[paralegal_hourly_rate] = 150
values[advanced_deposit] = 500
```

Then I can just insert values[advanced_deposit] wherever I'd like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the real strings (with quotes and everything)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the strings and get the keys and build a new object from the given data.

```js
var string1= '[atty_hourly_rate],[paralegal_hourly_rate],[advanced_deposit]',
    string2 = '250,150,500',
    keys = string1.split(',').map(function (a) { return a.slice(1, -1); }),
    object = string2.split(',').reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        r[keys[i]] = a;
        return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I noticed I never said thank you here, so thank you!